# Laravel Dependecy injection in job's constructor vs handle method, does it make any difference?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I have one Job and that require some service objects in order to perform business logic. I am making service object using dependency injection inside `handle()` method of job.

```
  $this->propertyService = app()->make(PropertyService::class);
  $propertyIds = $this->propertyService->buildSearchQuery($this->filter, $this->excludedPropertyIds)->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

But sometimes it running fine but sometimes is gives exception

`Call to undefined method PropertyService::buildSearchQuery()`

Now My question is,
dependency injection should be in constructor or handle method?

Any suggestions and corrections are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: its right in the documentation  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#handle-method-dependency-injection  .... also you are not doing dependency **injection** currently

Comment: and there is no dependency injection done on the constructor, the constructor is what receives the data for the job when you create the job

Answer (score 2):

I use `handle()` for dependency injection, and it's running well. Here's my code

```php
/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(WhatsappService $whatsappService)
{
    $whatsappService->SendMessage($this->wa_number, $this->wa_message);
}
```

Comment: Dont you need to Register your service in AppServiceProvider using bindMethod() ? as this link suggest? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#handle-method-dependency-injection

Comment: @AmrishKakadiya The note is: `Note that we are able to type-hint dependencies on the handle method of the job. The Laravel service container automatically injects these dependencies.` And the next line is: `If you would like to take total control over how the container injects dependencies into the handle method, you may use the container's bindMethod method.` So, I think it's clear enough,